# Does $x \perp (y,z)$ imply $x \perp y \mid z$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Does $x \perp (y,z)$ imply $x \perp y \mid z$, where $\perp$ denotes stochastic independence?

I was told it is true and the following is the proof (which I believe is wrong):

We want to show that $p(x,y,z) = p(x)p(y,z)$ implies $p(x,y \mid z)=p(x \mid z) p(y \mid z)$.

then:

$$p(x,y \mid z) = \frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(z)} = p(x) \frac{p(y,z)}{p(z)} = p(x)p(y \mid z)$$

QED...Except that, that is not what conditional independence means. The correct conclusion should have arrived at: $p(x \mid z) p(y \mid z)$.

1) Is this proof incorrect? (as I suspect it is)

2) If it is incorrect, I still don't know what the right answer is. I feel its false, but have been unable to produce a counter example. Any ideas anyone?

3) If its true, does someone have an **intuitive** explanation of why its correct? Or a different mathematical proof that is more intuitive/clear?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What has perpendicularity got to do with conditional probability?

Comment: @copper.hat The $\perp$ symbol is used to denote independence of random variables in probability theory; or sometimes $\perp\!\!\!\!\perp$ is used.

Comment: @copper.hat I dont understand how you can be asking what it has to do with conditional probabilities, it has everything to do with conditional probabilities, don't you see I am trying to ask if a specific form of independence implies conditions independences (which are related with conditional probabilities).

Comment: I am almost surely not a probabilist, but I have never seen the notation used for independence. Doob & Durrett which happen to be in front of me do not use that notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct and it shows the desired result.

To see this, sum on $y$ the identity $p(x,y\mid z)=p(x)p(y\mid z)$, valid for every $(x,y,z)$. One gets $p(x\mid z)=\sum\limits_yp(x,y\mid z)=p(x)\sum\limits_yp(y\mid z)=p(x)$ for every $(x,z)$ hence $p(x)=p(x\mid z)$ for every $(x,z)$.

Thus, the identity $p(x,y\mid z)=p(x)p(y\mid z)$ for every $(x,y,z)$ implies $p(x,y\mid z)=p(x\mid z)p(y\mid z)$ for every $(x,y,z)$, as desired.

Comment: I see. That is such an unintuitive way to show that. It would have never occurred to me. I wonder if there is a different solution that is more direct and that does not need ur middle paragraph (the part that is weird).

Comment: Does this only hold because we know from the premise that $x \perp (y,z)$ and thus, $x \perp z$?

Comment: We know nothing from the premise, as the answer shows we *prove* the independence of x and z (by a quite intuitive approach, if you ask me).

Comment: we do know from the premise $x \perp z$ from the decomposition rule of independence statements.

Comment: We do know that if we are familiar with the subject, but we do not NEED to know that to solve the question.

Comment: sure, I see your point. I see your method doesn't use it. I guess it was more intuitive for me knowing $x \perp z$ but I do see your point. Thanks for your help btw. :)